# PyQt4 crash with progress bar

Tags: python, progress-bar, pyqt4

I am trying to make a download operation that has a progress bar that automatically progresses.

When I run this code the progress bar works fine but when I click with the mouse in the form the program stops working.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import urllib

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle('Cleanlooks')
label = QLabel()
progressx = QProgressBar(label)

url = "http://l3cdn.riotgames.com/ShellInstaller/EUNE/LeagueofLegends_EUNE_Installer_9_15_2014.exe"
name = url.split('/')[-1]
def report(count, blockSize, totalSize):
        global percent
        percent = int(count*blockSize*100/totalSize)

        sys.stdout.write("\r%d%%" % percent + ' complete')
        progressx.setValue(percent)
        label.show()

urllib.urlretrieve(url, name, reporthook=report)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the progress bar:

[image: Broken progress bar]

Comment: Please add the Traceback to your post, or if you don't get one, a more detailed explanation what happens if you try to run your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to update your UI by calling `show` within your loop, I would call `QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()` instead:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import urllib

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle('Cleanlooks')

progressx = QtGui.QProgressBar()
progressx.show()

url = "http://l3cdn.riotgames.com/ShellInstaller/EUNE/LeagueofLegends_EUNE_Installer_9_15_2014.exe"
name = url.split('/')[-1]
def report(count, blockSize, totalSize):
    global percent
    percent = int(count*blockSize*100/totalSize)

    sys.stdout.write("\r%d%%" % percent + ' complete')
    progressx.setValue(percent)

    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

urllib.urlretrieve(url, name, reporthook=report)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Alternatively, if its still not working as you intend, you could try to implement your downloading process within its own thread using [QThread](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthread.html) and pass the progress to your progress bar with a signal and slot structure. I can provide you with an example if you need.

Comment: ah thx a lot your are the best :)